# Prevent button submissions with bootbox confirm and display their values on message

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, bootbox

I have a simple form with 3 buttons, each doing a different action. On one's click I want the user to confirm his action using bootbox.confirm(). I want the confirmation box to display: "Are you sure for your choice:" + value. How can I achieve this?

HTML:

```
<form action="" method="post">
     <button  type="submit" name="action" value="success" class="confirm"></button>
     <button type="submit" name="action" value="fail" class="confirm"></button>
     <button type="submit" name="action" value="no exam" class="confirm</button>
</form>
```

Javascript / jquery I tried:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("click", ".confirm", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        bootbox.confirm("Are you sure for your choice?", function(result) {
        if (result) {
          console.log("user confirmed");
        } else {
            console.log("user declined");
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Is this the right way (with classes on every button) or I have to select the form?
I get the confirm box and the logs correctly, but on success i don't know how to submit. Also I don't know how to put the chosen value in the message.

Comment: Looks reasonable. I would move the e.preventDefault(); call to the callback for the confirmation box so you only cancel the action if the user doesn't confirm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully you've been able to figure this out, but if not here is all you were missing.
Also, because this flow is async, don't move the e.preventDefault() to the callback.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("click", ".confirm", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
        bootbox.confirm("Are you sure for your choice: "+$this.val()+"?", function(result) {
            if (result) {
                console.log("user confirmed");
            } else {
                console.log("user declined");
            }
        });
    });
});
```